# How can I post a partially completed form without overwriting old information?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model with a view that lets users edit certain properties.  There are several properties that I do not want to be accessible from the view, however, so I can't just dump everything into hidden fields for the postback.

I'm sure this is a common scenario, so is there an easy way to postback only changes from the view, such that properties stored in the database are not overwritten with null or default values?

I know I could store the model in a Session variable when the edit view is called and then check for changes when the form is posted back, but that feels kind of hacky?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of sending your domain model object to the view, use a separate view model that contains only the properties you want to display to the user. When the view model is posted back, retrieve the domain model and update its properties from the view model.

Comment: And for a versatile approach, you can use a library such as AutoMapper to dynamically copy over values from ViewModel to DomainModel.

Comment: Ah thanks, don't know why I didn't think of this.  I'm even using a view model already :)

Answer (score 0):

I find this utility to be handy for copying viewmodel to domain model. I found this somewhere else on internet, not my code...There were caveats like it may be a bit slow because of reflection. But it is working plenty fast for me. It is much more lightweight than automapper.

Here is code to copy view model to domain:

```
UtilityService.CopyValues(realPropertyViewModel, realProperty);
```

Here is the utility service method:

```
public static void CopyValues<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source, TTarget target)
    {
        var sourceProperties = typeof(TSource).GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead);

        foreach (var property in sourceProperties)
        {
            var targetProperty = typeof(TTarget).GetProperty(property.Name);

            if (targetProperty != null && targetProperty.CanWrite && targetProperty.PropertyType.IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
            {
                var value = property.GetValue(source, null);

                targetProperty.SetValue(target, value, null);
            }
        }
    }
```